# Typescript: remove function properties while keeping it callable

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to remove all Function properties like `apply` or `call` from one, while still keeping it callable?

I've tried [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=5&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEAUBO7I5oQDOUAvFAEQCGYYANiJVAD5VLX33NuUdcQcPKgCNUCACbCaOAOZwAthATBi0+stnAAFtLB5g6UJGkJqS6YYDKwHONmUAsAChj0eMjSYA6qh3o4YFx8QSJiAB4PJCgIAA9gZQlSKK8EAD5yKAB5BT9IxCQAGlgC1OCCMLSXFw1gGIAuEs8MBF9-QPLQ1BJ85swMigAKAEpyDIBvAF8XCBGXIA), but it dosent work:

```
type FunctionProperties =
  | "apply"
  | "call"
  | "caller"
  | "bind"
  | "arguments"
  | "length"
  | "prototype"
  | "name"
  | "toString";

type FunctionWithoutProperties<Func extends Function> = Omit<
  Func,
  FunctionProperties
>;

let e: FunctionWithoutProperties<Function> = () => {};
e(); // Err: Type 'Pick<Function, never>' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

Comment: I think [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEAUBO7I5oQDOUAvFAEQCGYYANiJVAD5VLX33NuUdcQcPKgCNUCACbCaOAOZwAthATBi0+stnAAFtLB5g6UJGkJqS6YYDKwHONmUAsAChj0eMjSYA6qh3o4YFx8QSJiAB4PJCgIAA9gZQlSKK8EAD5yWERogDIoACUIJHQcCUjs1OCCMIAaKAQIADdBNJcNYBjMgAougEpyDIBvKABffupSagQQKAmszwwEX39AqtDUEnKFzDSAbigAegP6iAgJKENZ4mJQqG1BCBcIPv2jqHQAa2oQJ4A6fnoL0Ox0EeBwLiAA) is the closest you'll get, unfortunately.  Shall I write that as an answer?  Why do you want this, anyway? It's a surprising behavior for `typeof x === "function"` not to imply `Function` prototype.

Comment: Also see [microsoft/TypeScript#27575](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27575)

Comment: @jcalz I am writing a module exposing a function with properties (not always the same ones) added to the function while runtime. These can include `"name"` etc., hence the presence of a name attribute (even if it is never) without there being one is misleading. 

I agree that not having a Function prototype on a function can be suprising, but for my usecase it doesnt matter (its a already bound function with an irrelevant name & length etc.).

Comment: @jcalz Dont answere it yet, ill start a bounty tomorrow. Maybe someone knows a hack around this. Otherwise sure.

Comment: If you're writing the module then you can avoid this, right? Can your use case be satisfied by leaving the `Function` prototype alone and just adding a single `props` property to hold these extra properties called `name` or `length` or anything else? I think if you want to see TS changed to support call signatures without the `Function` prototype (as in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29261#issuecomment-451536491)) then a compelling use case is important, such as an existing popular JS library that works this way. Right now it's too easy to say "don't do that".